# Using secure proxies with Google Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, proxy, https, chromium

Whenever I use a secure proxy with Google Chrome I get `ERR_PROXY_CERTIFICATE_INVALID`, I tried a lot of different scenarios and versions.

## The certificate

I'm using a self-signed certificate:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 1024
openssl req -new -key key.pem -out request.pem
openssl x509 -req -days 30 -in request.pem -signkey key.pem -out certificate.pem
```

**Note:** this certificate works (with a warning since it's self-signed) when I try to setup a simple HTTPS server.

## The proxy

Then I start a secure proxy on `localhost:8080`. There are a several ways to accomplish this, I tried:

- a custom [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) script;
- [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org);
- [node-spdyproxy](https://github.com/igrigorik/node-spdyproxy) (OK, this involves SPDY too, but later... the problem is the same);
- [...]

## The browser

Then I run Google Chrome with:

```
google-chrome --proxy-server=https://localhost:8080 http://superuser.com
```

to load, say, `http://superuser.com`.

## The issue

All I get is:

```
Error 136 (net::ERR_PROXY_CERTIFICATE_INVALID): Unknown error.
```

in the window, and something like:

```
[13633:13639:1017/182333:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_nss.cc(790)] CERT_PKIXVerifyCert for localhost failed err=-8179
```

in the console.

**Note:** this is not the big red warning that complains about insecure certificates.

---

Now, I have to admit that I'm quite *n00b* for what concerns certificates and such, if I'm missing some fundamental points, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try importing that certificate into your system's certificate store and trust it. Chrome uses the OS to validate the security certificate.

I think it is very understandable that Chrome gives you an error instead a warning when the proxy's certificate is invalid because the proxy feature is probably implemented as a transparent add-on to its networking components. Requiring an additional UI to confirm the certificate of the proxy does not seem to be a useful feature.

The following steps will do the trick:

1. Generate the key and the certificate:

   ```
   openssl genrsa -out key.pem 1024
   openssl req -new -key key.pem -subj "/CN=localhost" -out req.pem
   openssl x509 -req -days 30 -in req.pem -signkey key.pem -out cert.pem
   ```

   Note that the only mandatory field is `CN` (`CommonName`) and **must** be the same domain of the one of the proxy.
2. Add the certificate to the system database using `certutil` (from package `libnss3-tools` in Debian):

   ```
   certutil -d "sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb" -A -n dummy -i cert.pem -t C
   ```

   `dummy` is just a nickname and can be anything, but make sure to provide the `-t C` option.

Comment: Your answer points me in the right direction, I didn't know that Chrome used the system's database to validate the certificates. I'll edit your answer to provide the detailed solution.