# How to debug ERR_PROXY_CERTIFICATE_INVALID?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, proxy, ssl, certificate

I am trying to encrypt communication between Chrome with a squid forward proxy. I provided a self-signed certificate and clearly something is wrong with it because Chrome fails with ERR_PROXY_CERTIFICATE_INVALID.

Yes, I have installed the self-signed certificate into the `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`.

Is there a way to get a hint from Chrome regarding what it did not like about the certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up filing a [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1130233) for this issue and their suggestion was to:

1. Disable the proxy configuration in chrome
2. Hit the proxy server as if it was a webpage
3. The conventional error dialog will display allowing you to debug the certificate error.

For example, if your proxy is listening to proxy.com on port 1234 then you should hit https://proxy.com:1234/ in Chrome without the use of a proxy.

Secondly, I ended up figuring out the problem with my particular certificate. My proxy server does not have a public hostname, just a public IP address.

I was generating the certificate like this:

`openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.crt -subj /CN=<ip> -addext subjectAltName=DNS:<hostname>,IP:<ip>`

Where `<hostname>` was some incorrect guess of what the hostname should be.

It turns out that if Chrome references a proxy server by IP address (not hostname) then you must omit the `DNS` entry from the SSL certificate. The following command-line worked for me:

`openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.crt -subj /CN=<ip> -addext subjectAltName=IP:<ip>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar thread regarding of using secure proxies with Google Chrome, you could have a look: [Using secure proxies with Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/489042/using-secure-proxies-with-google-chrome)